# Unit test that proves code avoids infinite loop

Tags: python, unit-testing, infinite-loop

I'm getting better at python but I wanted to find a way to prove that a piece of code is not in an infinite loop. Say I have a method foo() that has an infinite loop and an argument attempts that gets decremented each time. If the loop breaks out when attempts reaches zero I'm golden but in case I left a bug in my code, it would loop forever. For example, say I accidentally increment rather than decrements, is there a way for a unit test to detect the infinite loop and fail the test? Sorta of like a watchdog on a processor that detects if a process is taking up all the CPU cycles. See the following code:

```
# Given the following set of methods
def foo(attempts):
  while(attempts >= 0)
    attempts += 1 # OH OH!! ACCIDENTAL INFINITE LOOP!!!!
    # Keep doing work until attempts reaches zero (or so was expected...)

  return True # return true once broken out of the loop


# Here comes the Unit test
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_foo(self):
    self.assertTrue(foo(5)) # Test foo - but how to test that an inf loop is not present??
```

Comment: ... just let it there and your build will timeout though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests generally rely on the code under test creating some kind of observable result - a return value, a change in object state or an exception for example - that can be inspected by the test code.  Code that never finishes executing doesn't fit easily with this paradigm, but there are a few approaches you could take.

1. In your test, execute the method in a thread; in the main thread, periodically check how long the test has been running and raise an `AssertionError` if it's been running for too long.
2. If possible, design your code in a a way that does not require a potentially infinite loop.  For example, you could use a for loop so that completion is guaranteed:

   `for x in range(attempts):
       if can_we_break_now():
           break`
3. If your use case requires that `attempts` be mutated within the loop, try to extract the mutation code into a function and write tests to demonstrate that the function cannot assign an illegal value to `attempts`.

Comment: I see - I think your thread idea is the closest thing that I am looking for. I mean I trust I can code such that it doesn't involve infinite loops but the idea is to look at the code like a black box and I'm not privy to its inner workings.